# Why is one object bigger than the other (overlaps out of the sides) - CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, width

I'm trying to create a header with an image, fade over it and a title & sub-title. I created a new div for the fade box (& a separate div for the h1 & h2 so it could be at the bottom of the image). But somehow the fade container is wider than the image and I don't know how to make them the same size!
I'd be very grateful for any help. I'm very new to all this!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZhLn.png

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>
    <img src="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h2>subtitle</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.1));
}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post more code, Nicola, as the code you posted works as expected using [your pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZhLn.png) as `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZhLn.png">`. It fully fills `<header>` ... (actually, `header` is sized to `img` proportions)

Comment: Thanks @Rene, what additional info do you need? If the `img` fills the `header`, why is the `container` bigger? I just want the `container` and `img` to be the same width

Comment: That's why you need to post more of the CSS/HTML code you actually use. The code above as-is works and does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Rene I've added a couple of bits but that's all I had for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd that your code is doing this but try to make the img 100% the width of the container.

Otherwise experiment a little, if you want the header, container and image to be the width of the screen, set the width of header to 100vh and then set the container and image to 100%

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not a problem! If this has worked for you, please feel free to press the tick mark next to my answer :D